# how to feed pybrain ffn with one entry (to already trained network)?

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I need to train network and then feed it with test data one by one. Is there some example or doc including it?

To achieve that I serialized trained network and I use it with every new incoming entry.
The problem is, I got crash from `_convertToOneOfMany` and even tho I understand its purpose (from [here](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/datasets.html)) I do not understand how it exactly works.

Its behaviour is not deterministic for me. It must interpret somehow classes and labels and there must be some requirement I am missing. It works for whole data set, however if I take just random line it goes crazy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ffn_iris.py", line 29, in <module>
tstdata._convertToOneOfMany()
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3-py2.6.egg/pybrain/datasets/classification.py", line 142, in _convertToOneOfMany
newtarg[i, int(oldtarg[i])] = bounds[1]
IndexError: index (2) out of range (0<=index<1) in dimension 1
```

EDIT: 
  to be more precise let me tell you what I am doing: I want to train network for the most famous NN example in the Internet ;) - Iris Dataset.

It is something like that:

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,0
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,0
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,0
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,0
etc...
```

The last zero it the class. Whole dataset holds 60 rows. 20 for 0, 20 for 1 and 20 for 2.

I read the file with data and construct dataset:

```
alldata = ClassificationDataSet(4, class_labels=['Iris-setosa', 
                                                 'Iris-versicolor',
                                                 'Iris-virginica'])

--- loop here ---

alldata.addSample(line[0:4], line[4])


--- create testing and training sets ---
tstdata, trndata = alldata.splitWithProportion(0.7)


--- converted matrixes ---
trndata._convertToOneOfMany()
tstdata._convertToOneOfMany()

--- not important, just for completeness ----
fnn = buildNetwork(trndata.indim, 10, trndata.outdim, outclass=SoftmaxLayer)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(fnn, dataset=trndata,
                          momentum=0.01, verbose=True,
                          weightdecay=0.01)
```

My problem relates to `_convertToOneOfMany()`. When dataset or datafile holds just couple entries (not 60, divided into three classes) it crashes with exception from the beginning of the question.

Example of crashing datset:

```
 6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,1
 6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,1
 6.2,3.4,5.4,2.3,2
 6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,0
```

Example of working one:

```
 6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,1
 6.2,3.4,5.4,2.3,2
 6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,0
```

How can `convertToOneOfMany()` be connected to number of entries in the dataset or size of one class subset? One row entries crash as well..

Answer (score 0):

It may be good if you paste more of your code. Regarding your question, it is on their documentation: http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/network.html
Basically is this command: net.activate([2, 1])
it this case the network has 2 inputs, and he/she inputs the values 2 and 1
I recommend you going through their documentation

Comment: I expanded the question - could you take a look? Thanks! Is there any forum or mailing list for experienced users of PyBrain?